# Printing the last element received from an API

Tags: python, json, api

I'm making a bot that compares the last buys and sells orders received by fetching a cryptocurrencie's exchange and prints the difference. 
My problem, right now, is that it prints the last order received over and over, i think it's because of the while loop. Is there a way to make it print only the last two without printing the same thing more times? I was thinking of using OrderedDict but i don't know how to use it on Json. Here is the code involved:

```
    import time, requests, json




> while True:
>     BU = requests.session() 
>     URL = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-DOGE'
>     r = BU.get(URL, timeout=(15, 10))
>     time.sleep(1)
>     MarketPairs = json.loads(r.content) 
>     for element in MarketPairs['result']:
>         id = element['Id']
>         price = element['Price']
>         tot = element['Total']
>         time = element['TimeStamp']
>         type = element['OrderType']
> 
> 
>         if time > '2017-12-11T21:37:01.103':
>             print type, id, tot, price, time
>             time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want...
It will print only last price, and only if it's different from previous one

```
import requests as req
import time

previous=None
while 1:
    url='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-DOGE'
    response = req.get(url,timeout=(15,10)).json()
    result = response["result"]

    last_price_dict  = result[0]
    id=last_price_dict["Id"]
    price = last_price_dict["Price"]
    total = last_price_dict["Total"]
    timestamp = last_price_dict["TimeStamp"]
    order_type=last_price_dict["OrderType"]
    this_one = (id, total, price, timestamp)
    if id != previous:
        print(this_one)
        previous = id
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: I have been trying to find a solution for about 3 days to this problem, you have no idea how grateful i am to you. Could you just quickly explain where i was mistaking? The code now is working wonderfully, thank you, you really made my day.

Comment: You while loop is fine. But, first of all your code goes through all the results, while you only need the first one. Second, the part `if time > '2017-12-11T21:37:01.103' is hardcoded, so once something has been printed, it will keep being printed every time, since time doesn't go backward :) All you needed to do is to check Id, because Bittrex are smart enough to change it only if the price changes, they won't send you twice the same thing. So once you checked for the new Id, you are sure you have a new information => so print it